# Why use ob_start and eval instead of using a simple include in this Joomla Plugin?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, plugin, plugin-events

I was looking at the code of a Plugin for Joomla! CMS for a functionality I need: the possibility to run custom PHP scripts when a [Joomla! Plugin/Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) is fired.

I wanted to learn the mechanism used by this plugin and the code looked to me a bit odd (I'm quite a novice in PHP, so I guess I'm missing something).

Here is a snippet of the code for one of the above mentioned Events, the full plugin can be downloaded [here](http://joomla.impression-estudio.gr/add-custom-php/download.php).

```
function onBeforeCompileHead()
{
    if (strcmp($this->params->get('onBeforeCompileHead_custom_php_file_path'),'')!=0)
    {
        $custom_php_file_path = JPATH_SITE.DS.$this->params->get('onBeforeCompileHead_custom_php_file_path');
        ob_start();
        include($custom_php_file_path);
        $php = ob_get_contents();
        eval($php);
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

I don't get why it has been used `ob_start` to capture the `include` content to then `eval` it (btw isn't `eval` *evil*? or because there is no user input to eval it's *ok* to use?).

I tried removing all that part, using isntead a simply `include`
statement and it worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: i cant see anything you're missing either. Contact the author to get their thoughts?